# Half of my mesh/texture is blurred

Tags: texturing

For some reason, half of my texture on the mesh is blurred... I did not use any special nodes or settings or anything, just applied an Image Texture node...

Any idea why this might be?

Here is the .blend file

[image]

and a screenshot:

[image]

Thanks guys

Comment: The blend you have is missing the texture. You can pack all external data like images with File -> External Data -> Automatically Pack Into .blend. From first guess though, I feel like Blender stretched your texture. Did you manually unwrap or Smart UV Project, or did you just unwrap without seams?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks man, was wondering if the file will include the texture/image as well.... Yeah, forgot about the seam! Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to provide a proper UV map to make this work. The reason why it looks like this is that currently your UV map is stretching just horribly, check this screenshot:

[image: stretching]

When I select the bottom of the vase, I can see that those faces cover a **very small** area of the UV editor, causing the texture to stretch like it does:

[image: stretching UVs]

In essence, 75% of the surface of the vase are mapped to something like 4% of the UV space. This just cannot work. Try unwrapping the vase by placing seams down the side on two opposite sides, and also around the n-gon on the bottom, then the unwrap function will give you something like this:

[image: UVs unwrapped]

The vase then will receive the texture like this:

[image: vase mapped]

Check the Blender manual on UV unwrapping techniques for further information:
https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping/index.html

Comment: Ah right, forgot about the seams!