# Cycles does not show textures

Tags: rendering, texturing

So, I DO have the UV unwrapped, looks alright in Blender render, not when I switch to Cycles though ...[image: Cycles render]

[image: Blender Render]

Would post the file, its 70 mB though... for some reason,...

EDIT: not sure about how my question is different from the similar question asked, but I did not see any solution in the [How to show textures in the 3D View editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-show-textures-in-the-3d-view-editor) other similar thread/question....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show textures in the 3D View editor?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-show-textures-in-the-3d-view-editor)

Comment: Hmm checked, 'his' solution did not worked for me.... no idea where the problem might be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this vase you have three materials in the material slots tab. As you can see in your screenshot, you are editing the second one at the moment. Trouble is, that material (I know that from the last file you provided in another question [Half of my mesh/texture is blurred](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63293/half-of-my-mesh-texture-is-blurred)) is not assigned to any face of your model, that's why you do not see the texture.

Either select all faces in **Edit Mode** and click the **assign** button in the material tab. This will assign the currently active material to the mesh faces. Or alternatively, delete the other materials (if you don't plan to use them). Then make sure the image texture node is selected in the Node Editor, and the 3D View is set to textured. That should do.

Comment: Hah, that was so funny. The solution to this issue was solved by ONE click on the Assign button :) Totally did not know you need to assign material first. Thanks man!